# regex - capture space delimited word

Tags: regex, go

I have a string:

`2001 970451 4 l 97 0451 iver b y c 3 0 1 8 4 1 4 hundred 2001 970451 nama  4 l 97 0451 iver hundred blah`

I need an appropriate regular expression to capture series of characters and spaces such as `b y c 3 0 1 8 4 1 4`?

I have tried:

`(\b[a-z0-9]{1}\s{1})+` - I get `l`

EDIT:

To further explain what I need, I need to be able to capture similar series of text where a single alphanum character is continuously/repeatedly followed by single space character to a point where this is no longer true.

Comment: Every single entity matches once so `{1}` is redundant. Your regex is equivalent to `(\b[a-z0-9]\s)+`

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Is `4 l` a valid thing to capture? If not, why not?

Comment: Your regexp is correct. I assume you request a capturing group, then you will get only one alpha + space. You have to request the whole matched substring or change your regexp like: ((\b[a-z0-9]{1}\s{1})+). This defines one capturing group for the whole matched expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `regexp` a hard requirement?

It would be far simpler for you, in the long term, to just use something like `strings.Fields` and filter the resulting array by length (you can apply any other requirements too).

Example:
*(Give it a try on the playground! https://play.golang.org/p/Ue2wO5d-Te)*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func CaptureGroups(input string) (output [][]string) {
    fields := strings.Fields(input)

    var group []string
    for _, field := range fields {
        if len(field) == 1 {
            group = append(group, field)
        } else {
            if len(group) > 0 {
                output = append(output, group)
                group = make([]string, 0)
            }
        }
    }

    return
}

func main() {
    input := "2001 970451 4 l 97 0451 iver b y c 3 0 1 8 4 1 4 hundred 2001 970451 nama  4 l 97 0451 iver hundred blah"
    output := CaptureGroups(input)

    fmt.Printf("Groups: %q", output)
}
```

Comment: The capture groups returned using this approach is the most accurate I have seen. Better than any regex pattern so far.

Comment: @Nedy: I always think twice about using regexp, most of the time is overkill but hey... Every tool for its job!

Answer (score 1):

i think this will work: [`(( [^ ])+ )`](https://regex101.com/r/sJ6wR1/1)
your string will be in capture group 1

Answer (score 0):

\040 matches exactly the space character.

so to match something like `b y c 3 0 1 8 4 1 4 you need

```
[a-z]\040[a-z]\040[a-z]\040[0-9]\040[0-9]\040[0-9]\040[0-9]
```

Comment: `' '` also matches exactly the space character and is much more readable

Comment: This is very specific and will not play well when used in arbitrary text.